# DDD. When to use aggregate root in a tree-like structure?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

In a bounded context I created an `Entity` which serves as an aggregate for other objects in this context. The problem is, an instance of an `Entity` may be in child-parent relation with another `Entity`. In terms of a database it means, that there is a `parent_id` field which references a row in the same `entities` table.

And the question is, from DDD point of view, is it ok to make an instance of an `Entity` an argument of its own constructore function? Or is better to use an aggregate root (or an `Entity` identifier). So, which way is better:

```
class Entity {
     public constructor (arg1, arg2, Entity parent) {
         ...
         this.setParent(parent);
     }
}
```

or this way:

```
 class Entity {
     public constructor (arg1, arg2, int parent_id) {
         ...
         this.setParentId(parent_id);
     }
 }
```

Comment: In general primitive obsession is bad. What is an int in domain terms?

Comment: @GraemeMiller. So, in terms of pure theory it's ok to store references to another aggregates and use them as parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Just because you have a tree like structure doesn't mean that all **Entities** in this structure should be part of the same **Aggregate**.

You can design your system to have each **Entity instance** in it's own aggregate. Since each entity has a parent you have to **reference** this parent.

- One way to do this is to have an **Object reference** like in your first example
- Another way is to use **Reference by identity** like in your second example

If you use **Object reference** that means that you must load all the objects referenced together from the DB. This may cause you to load huge amount of them. If you application doesn't require you to do so it's best avoided.

If you choose to use **Object reference** then you can pass an Entity to the Constructor like in your ecample.

If you use **Reference by ID** you can only load one object, then if needed, you can load another by using the ID. This is useful if you want to have multiple aggregates that only need each other in specific situations and you don't need to load them all the time together because your application doesn't require you to do so.

Here's an example:

```
public TreeNode {
  public Guid ParentID { get; private set; }
}

public void DoSomethingToNode(Guid nodeId) {

  var node = TreeNodeRepository.GetById(nodeId);
  var parent = TreeNodeRepository.GetById(node.ParentID);

  // do stuff with parent and child.
}
```

If you haven't read the [DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), I recommend it.

[This essay from Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) is also great on modeling aggregates